# liquibase SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: mysql, maven, azure, ssl, liquibase

I have a problem integrating liquibase maven execution with a mysql 5.7 database provided by azure as a Service.
the error log is:

*Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:status (default-cli) on project — : Error setting up or running Liquibase: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 575 ms ago. Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly.*

this is the connection string I give to liquibase:

*jdbc:mysql://server-name:3306/db-name?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false*

Any suggestion?
I have just tryed to set -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
but nothing changed..

Comment: solved by pointing to mysql db on aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed issue using version 8.0.12 of mysql unit connector and updating jdbc URL with useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC for the jdbc time zone parameter

Answer (score 0):

mysql on azure uses by default the ssl security protocol